# Kendo UI progress bar inside react-tooltip not working

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip, react-tooltip

I have a simple div which uses react-tooltip
Inside the tooltip I am trying to render kendo progress bar but it doesn't seem to be working, the bar is shown but the progress is not shown

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import 'react-tooltip/dist/react-tooltip.css'
import { Tooltip as ReactTooltip } from 'react-tooltip'
import { ProgressBar } from '@progress/kendo-react-progressbars';


const App = () => {
 
  const TooltipContentTemplate = () => {

    return <div>
       <ProgressBar value={20} labelVisible={false}/>
        </div>
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mb-4" id="1"
       data-tooltip-html={ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<TooltipContentTemplate></TooltipContentTemplate>)}>
      Hello World
      </div>
      <ReactTooltip style={{zIndex:"10", backgroundColor:"black",color:"black",width:"200px",height:"300px",border:'1px solid black'}} anchorId="1"/>
      <div>
       <ProgressBar value={20} labelVisible={false}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
);
```

[Without hover on Hello World](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u3Su.png)
[On hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef196.png)

I am trying with above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue related to the usage of `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`, not sure what though.

You can try putting the tooltip content inside the tooltip component directly, instead of using `data-tooltip-html` on the anchor.

Your code updated:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "react-tooltip/dist/react-tooltip.css";
import { Tooltip as ReactTooltip } from "react-tooltip";
import { ProgressBar } from "@progress/kendo-react-progressbars";

const App = () => {
  const TooltipContentTemplate = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProgressBar value={20} labelVisible={false} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mb-4" id="1">
        Hello World
      </div>
      <ReactTooltip
        style={{
          zIndex: "10",
          backgroundColor: "black",
          color: "black",
          width: "200px",
          height: "300px",
          border: "1px solid black"
        }}
        anchorId="1"
      >
        {/* tooltip content here */}
        <TooltipContentTemplate></TooltipContentTemplate>
      </ReactTooltip>
      <div>
        <ProgressBar value={20} labelVisible={false} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("my-app"));
```